# Слежение за зрачками, слежение за взглядом

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv

В приложении на WPF нужно поддержать функциональность по слежению за зрачками человека через вебкамеру (то есть смотрит ли он прямо или в сторону).
Знаю что подобные вещи возможно сделать на OpenCV или EmguCV. Но хотя бы приблизительной наводки по реализации или плану я не нашел, не говоря уже о цельных решениях.

Может у кого есть опыт по данной теме или опыт работы с перечисленными библиотеками(в каком направлении двигаться).

Comment: вот нагуглилось https://www.learnopencv.com/head-pose-estimation-using-opencv-and-dlib/

Comment: ключевые слова opencv eye gaze detection = https://github.com/iitmcvg/eye-gaze

Comment: Предлагаю воспользоваться алгоритмом кода фримана. Самый простой способ это настроить алгоритм так что бы можно было найти приблизительно глаза и сами зрачки. Что то подобное есть в самой опен св. При нахождении двух зрачков можно определить относительный центр самих зрачков относительно центра глаз. Единственная проблема будет в подбирании коэффициентов что бы глаза были примерно одинаковы ) Я думаю что это самый простой способ реализовать данную функциональность. Если вы хотите сделать это с нуля.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо за ссылку, я это видел,  но оно не хочет работать, по не понятным мне причинам.

Comment: @jNX а что касается вебкамеры? Какой алгоритм взаимодействия с камерой? Делать скрин с камеры в определенный интервал и анализировать его?

Comment: @Ага к сожалению я точно сказать не могу, так как изучал cv в университете но на моей памяти что алгоритм достаточно простой и гибкий и я думаю находить контура в рантайме будет не составит проблем. Самая проблема настроить его что бы выделяло не прям все линии. Постараюсь поискать лекции на эту тему вечером и скину вам.